# AXIS2 Client not able to download attachment where a CXF Client does

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I'm trying to invoke a web service (SOAP) using Axis2

the web service is developed with CXF

the service I'm trying to invoke is supposed to return a binary document (PDFs)

using SOAPUI, the service responses correctly and I can download the PDF

Here's the stack I'm using client side (I used Eclipse to generate Stub)

**Axis 1.6.2**

**JRE 1.6_45**

here's the call I'm trying to do :

```
    @Test
public void process() throws RemoteException {
    DocumentService service = new DocumentServiceProxy("THE SERVICE URL");
    service.download("MY_DOCUMENT_ID");
}
```

Here's the Exception :

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onStartChild(SimpleDeserializer.java:145)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
```

Please comment me to add more information

UPDATE :

by debugging the server side of the service , here's what I found :

```
WARNING: Error writing to XMLStreamWriter.
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to output second root, <soap:Fault>
```

and down in the stack trace

```
WARNING: Interceptor for {documentTarget}CXFDocumentServiceService#      {http://sei.ws.fast.cdc.com/}download has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not write attachments.
```

So , I replaced to jars in the AXIS client project in order to use same jars as server side

replaced [**wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar]** by [**woodstox-core-asl-4.3.0.jar**]

replaced [**geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar**] by [**stax-api-1.0-2.jar**]

Comment: please see UPDATE section

Comment: It seems that something related to shared non synchronized resource is happening but not enough information to figure it out. I'll try to develop a server app using AXIS in order to see if attachments will work.

Comment: it seems that it has something related with this bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/WSTX-260?jql=project%20%3D%20WSTX%20AND%20status%20%3D%20%22In%20Progress%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC